# Each options in dropdown needs to be truncated

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a list of options which are taken from database for dropdown. I have added jQuery to truncate each options in drop down. [Followed example](http://forum.jquery.com/topic/how-to-truncate-the-text-in-the-options-of-select-tag-by-adding-ellipsis-in-the-text). Here is my code

JS

```
$(function() {
     $('#id').each(function(){
            var text=$(this).text()
            $(this).val(text).text(text.substr(0,10)+'…').text();
      })
 });
```

> My expectation

greatcode1...

greatcode2...

greatcode3...

greatcode4...

greatcode5...

greatcode6...

greatcode7...

> Reality

greatcode1...

How should I change my code???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     $('#id option').each(function(){
            var text=$(this).text()
            $(this).val(text).text(text.substr(0,10)+'…');
      })
 });
```

Check http://jsfiddle.net/4K9hM/4/

Answer (score 2):

```
$('#id option').text(function(index, text) {
    if (text.length < 10) {
        return text;
    } else {
        return text.substr(0, 10) + '...';
    }
});
```